# Python Priting Out Something While Waiting For Long Output

Tags: python, python-2.7, time

I created a python file that collect data. After collecting all the data, it will print out "Done.". Sometimes, it might take atleast 3 minutes to collect all the data.

I would like to know how to print something like "Please wait..." for every 30 seconds, and it will stop after collecting all the data.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You can use threading. Do your work in a thread and have the timer in another thread. I would also give you code example but i am on my phone in the car at the stoplights.

Comment: you could use threading. **[have look at](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)**

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with multi threading, run your collect_data method in a separate thread and monitor this thread in the main thread.

Here is the code example:

```
import time
from threading import Thread


def collect_data():
    pass

t = Thread(target=collect_data)
t.start()

timeout = 30.0

while t.isAlive():
    time.sleep(0.1)
    timeout -= 0.1
    if timeout == 0.0:
        print 'Please wait...'
        timeout = 30.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print). It seems like you might have two issues: having a timer that triggers at a reliable interval (best handled through threading and the `time.sleep()` function), and forcing output while the processor is busy.

For this latter issue, the best tool is `sys.stdout.flush()` which pushes output to the current output device (this could be your console, or the iPython notebook output screen). This also works to print output from a function that has been called- useful if your computations are wrapped in another function.

Sample code:

```
import sys

def print_this(mystr):
   print(mystr)
   sys.stdout.flush()    

for i in range(1,100)
   print_this('hello world!')
```

Answer (score 0):

## You can simply creat a label and hide it, during collecting your data you can show it.

class collectdata(QDialog):
    def **init**(self, hbrk,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(collectdata, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)

```
    self.QBtn = QPushButton()            
    self.setFixedWidth(800)
    self.setFixedHeight(600)
    self.QBtn.clicked.connect(self.longprocess)
    layout = QFormLayout()
    layout.addRow(self.QBtn)

    self.lblwait = QLabel("Please Wait ...")
    layout.addRow(self.lblwait)
    self.lblwait.hide()

def longprocess(self):
    self.lblwait.show()
    #.... collect your data
    self.lblwait.hide()
```

Answer (score -3):

If the program would know how much data it is getting, you could set it up to function like a progress bar..